# Slow Cassandra query

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a cassandra table, representing a timeseries, with this primary key

```
PRIMARY KEY ((type, id), scope, namespace_type, namespace_group, 
name_attribute, event_time)
```

[image]

But queries are running too slow.

Slow query trace 3,020ms

```
select * FROM entity_attribute_history WHERE type=? AND id=? AND scope=? AND 
namespace_type=? AND namespace_group=? AND name_attribute=? AND event_time>=? 
AND event_time<=?
```

what should I have considered in the model?

EDIT:

```
nodetool cfhistograms
```

[image]

prometheus
[image]

Comment: there are many things here that should be taken into account - how many entries will be read for given time range, how many SSTables on given machine, what is the consistency level, do you have read repairs happening, etc.  First thing to do is to run this query with `tracing on` in `cqlsh`.  then look to output to proxystats, tablestats, etc. Look here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/bestPractices.html - two last documents - on data model/schema checks, an schema tuning

Comment: My guess would be that the partitions are huge.  Try running `nodetool cfhistograms` on that table, and see what the partition sizes look like.